# How does same address location give two different values?

Tags: c++

I have the following issue.  In the below code the address of the object variable p is same as the address of its first member 'a'. But when i print the value of p and a they are both. How come same address location holds two different values ?

```
class sample {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    //sample();
    sample(int x,int y, int z){
        a=x;
        b=y;
        c=z;
    }    

};


int main() {
    //sample p;
    //sample sample(2,3,4);
    sample p = sample(2,3,4);
    // cout<<"The value that is stored in the z is "<< p <<endl;
    printf("The value of the object handle p is %d \n",p); 
    printf("The address of the object handle p is %d \n",&p);
    //p->a =2;
    //p->b =3; This could be accessesd in the later part of the code.
    //p->c =4;

    printf("The address of a is %d\n",&(p.a));
    printf("The value stored in the a is %d\n",p.a);
    printf("The value stored in the b is %d\n",p.b);
    printf("The value stored in the c is %d\n",p.c);
}
```

The output of the above code is :

```
The value of the object handle p is 2358832
The address of the object handle p is 2358848
The address of a is 2358848
The value stored in the a is 2
The value stored in the b is 2358852
The value stored in the c is 2358856

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.2105 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Normally the first printf would cause a runtime error. The compiller should give a respective warning while compilling by the way.

Comment: You assumption is false. The 1st `printf` does not work as you expect. (It puts object p to stack and then reads the 1st `sizeof (int)` bytes as `int` value.) `printf` does use variadic arguments and is **not** type safe. Try this with `std::cout` instead. Then, it will probably even not compile. (because there is no output operator for class `sample`.)

Comment: No, I didn't get any compiler error. I have pasted the output from the terminal as it is. By the way I am using dev c++ and the compiler is TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit release.

Comment: You have **undefined behavior** for your `printf` statements. In particular, in common 64-bit Windows a data pointer is 64 bits while an `int` as expected by `%d` is just 32 bits. Use format `%p` for a data pointer. Turn up your compiler's warning level to get warnings about mistmatch between arguments and formats.

Comment: Btw. you may try something else: add a virtual method to your `sample` class. Then you will observe that `&p` is not anymore `&p.a` because the compiler will insert a virtual method table address in your object silently.

Comment: @Scheff . Correct ! with cout it doesn't even compile

Comment: @Scheff : Could you please elaborate more on why does the std::cout  doesn't behave as expected in this case ?

Comment: @Scheff            Yes, when I added a virtual method into the class 'sample' , the compiler failed to compile and gave the below error even with printf statement                               38 54 C:\Users\Divyakiran\Documents\kiran\Study\Dev_C++_work\sample3.cpp [Error] cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class sample' through '...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` uses variadic arguments. Although, I saw extensions in gcc to check variadic arguments against the format string, there is actually no really compile time check about type matches of arguments to format string.

Therefore, `printf` should not be used in C++. The type-safe alternative are streams.

Stream operators (actually these are overloaded shift operators) are available for built-in types as well as certain classes of the standard library (e.g. `std::string`).

To support stream output of an self-designed class the stream output operator has to be overloaded for it. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

class Sample {
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Sample&);
  private:
    int _a, _b, _c;
  public:
  Sample(int a, int b, int c): _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) { }

};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Sample &s)
{
  return out << s._a << ", " << s._b << ", " << s._c;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  Sample sample = Sample(123, 234, 345);
  std::cout << "sample: " << sample << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc on cygwin:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test-cout test-cout.cc

$ ./test-cout
sample: 123, 234, 345
```

I did make `a, b, c` `private` to demonstrate that the stream output operator may access them if made a `friend`.